# Differents drawer navigator for each user type in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm new using react native, and I came across a problem / question. I am implementing an application with two different user types: Teacher and Student. I would like to offer each type of user a drawer navigator appropriate to their functions.

Currently I have a stack navigator with login screens and after login I would like to know if it is possible to instantiate a different drawer for each type of user.
The structure I am wanting is as follows:

[Navigation tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFoIE.jpg)

Sorry for any mistake, I'm Brazilian and I'm using translator.

Comment: This documentation may help you with composition in reactjs https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawer navigator supports a custom component for the content: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent

You can provide a custom React component where you conditionally render different content based on the user type.